# Subject is not included in mail received using smtplib

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I am using smtplib in Python to send mail. I did below coding for same. Receiving mail successfully with right body and all but  is not having the Subject in it. It is showing as No Subject.

```
import smtplib


sender = 'singh@xyz.com'
receivers = ['singh2@xyz.com']

message = """From:  Center <singh@xyz.com>
To: To Singh <singh@xyz.com>
Subject: 'Message Status'

THis is e-mail Body.
"""


try:
    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('mail22.xyz.rdc', 25)
    smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
    smtpObj.quit()
    print("Successfully sent email")
except SMTPException:
    print("Error: unable to send email")
```

I tried to change subject as

```
Subject: Message Status
Subject: <Message Status>
```

But not worked. Expected that mail should have Subject Line as 'Message Status'

Comment: What are you reading the mail with? And could the mail server rewrite headers for any reasons?

Comment: This is the small part of my script related to mail.
Actually, I am parsing a list and sending that in Mail Body. And I am getting that as expected in mail received.

But I am not getting the subject.

I tried to run same script in another new File just to check and it's working fine there.

Comment: What you show here looks correct. Does it exhibit the problem on your system?